# Sort of Login without database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, form-authentication

I have an web service call where I get a list of 5 access codes, a user will be able to login with one of those codes(basically feel special that they have the code, but nothing secure about it, as they could share codes if they wanted to)

I would want to be able to use the [Authorize] if at all possible. Won't be using a database, just that one api call.  Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried a simple if statement comparing the known codes against the users input? For what you are asking for I think it may be as simple as that

Comment: @JoeW well yes, but I need to make it global, so any page they try to access (if there is no cookie saved for them) it will push to the login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the codes on login with a simple if statement

```
if{code1 == "edgwreggw" || code2 == "etgwg"....)
{
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(data.username, true);
}

else
{
 login fail
}
```

Webconfig

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/UserAuthentication/SignIn" timeout="10" defaultUrl="~\Home\Index" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Well I need to know how to make this global, so any page it will push them to the login page

Comment: awesome, then just use [Authorize] as with usual login/password?

Comment: yes should work make sure you add using System.Web.Security; in your security

Answer (score 2):

So.. you really don't care about security but you want to hand out 1 of 5 codes to random people to use your web service.

Simple enough.  Put the codes in an array.  Check if the code passed in is one of those values.  If not, end the request.  If it is, process the request.

Comment: But how do I use [Authorize](or something like that) to check each page?

Comment: You can't use `AuthorizeAttribute` for this as it's specialized for true logins. However, you can create your own subclass of `ActionFilterAttribute` to do whatever processing you need. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.108).aspx